# Поиск картинок, изображений на сайте

Tags: php, изображения, search

Как сделать поиск на сайте, на языке php который выводит только изображения. 
К моему сожалению, получилось сделать только не сложную форму форму для получения данных.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие можно использовать парсеры сайта?
Желательно с примерами, так как нет в этом опыта.

Спасибо.

Comment: Парсить данные. Покажите что пытались сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: <form class="containert" action="/studio.html/search/" target="_blank">
          <div class="search-box" id="SBox">
          <input id="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
            <div class="also search-link" onclick="searchbox(0)" id="searchclick"></div></div>
        </form>
получилось написать только форму а дальше знания кончились и все попытки найти что-либо нормальное тоже

Comment: К сожалению, это не портал выполнения задач. Прежде всего Вам необходимо почитать дополнительную информацию о парсерах и как ими пользоваться. Советую Вам внимательно прочитать это - https://xdan.ru/uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html , это https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=639 и это https://habr.com/ru/post/69149/ И попробовать написать по примерам свой парсер. Если уже с кодом у Вас возникнут сложности - смело пишите сюда, прикладывая свой код. И Вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: я не прошу готовое решение, мне нужно хотя бы направление где мне что изучить, может с этим кто сталкивался

Comment: Понимаю Вас. Вам необходимо почитать про работу парсеров. Они так и называются.Это достаточно обёмный пласт информации, чтобы дать детальный ответ. Выше я Вам прислал ссылки, по которым можно почитать информацию по основным принципам их работы, и даже примеры, как можно их использовать. Существуют парсеры для разных языков программирования. Я постарался найти для Вас именно для `php`. Попробуйте почитать данную информацию и реализовать по примерам свой вариант. Если не получится - Вы можете написать сюда ещё вопрос, с примером Вашего кода. Тогда Вам точно смогут помочь.